# Removing the space between a plot generated by R and the caption in an Rtex file

Tags: r, latex

I am trying to edit an Rtex file and I'm creating plots. I have a plot below, which does compile. However, there is an empty white space below the caption. I can't figure out how to remove it. I have tried to search for solutions but to no avail:

- https://support.sisense.com/kb/en/article/remove-whitespace-margins-from-plotly-charts - Relevant but for plotly. Was not
  able to adapt it to my R code.
- http://ostack.cn/qa/?qa=829717/ - Involved Python rather than R. I
  could not adapt the solution into the R plot.
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273786/latex-files-generated-by-tikzdevice-leaves-large-space-between-image-and-caption - Involved tikzpicture instead of R. I could not adapt the solution to the R plot.

The code which I'm running as well as the output is shown below. I am grateful if someone can help me. I have also tried the trimmws() function but it gave the following error:

```
## "Error in mysub(paste0("^", whitespace, "+"), x):  argument"x" is missing, with no default."
```

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%Packages
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{F-distribution}
\maketitle
\section{Diagram showing the $F$-distribution for a selected pair of values of the degree of freedom}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[h!]
<<echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE, fig.width=5, fig.height=5>>=
curve(df(x, df1=20, df2=20))
@
\caption{Hi}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture showing the code output]

Comment: Apologies for the unclear and not useful question, and for not showing any relevant research effort. Can someone please explain the downvote and how I can improve my question?

Comment: Can you share the intermediate .tex file so we can check of the whitespace is actually part of the image or if it is added by tex?

Comment: Hi samcarter. Thank you for your comment. I have edited the post with the .tex code and the picture of the output. I am sorry but I am not sure if the whitespace is part of the image or created by tex. I also sincerely apologise for the poor/unclear/low-effort and not useful question. I hope my edits improved it a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image does have quite a lot of white space around it. You can move the caption further up with this quick hack:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%Packages
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{F-distribution}
\maketitle
\section{Diagram showing the $F$-distribution for a selected pair of values of the degree of freedom}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[h!]
<<echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE, fig.width=5, fig.height=5>>=
curve(df(x, df1=20, df2=20))
@
\vskip-1cm
\caption{Hi}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]